# Meteor C3 charts based on D3 - multiple charts?

Tags: meteor

EDIT: clone this repository for a non working reproduction.  https://github.com/FickleLife/meteor-c3-test

I am using https://github.com/peernohell/meteor-c3.js/

I pull two examples off the C3 site http://c3js.org/examples.html and can get them to display once on the page, but when I try to add a second on the same page the first disappears. There's no console error and the javascript variables are different.

chart 1 html template:

```
<template name="chart_cp_overview">
    <div id="cpOverview"></div>
</template>
```

chart 1 js helper:

```
Template.chart_cp_overview.rendered = function () {
var cpOverview = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200],
            ['data2', 130, 100]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2']
        ]
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [{value:0}]
        }
    }
});
}
```

chart 2 html template:

```
<template name="chart_status">
    <div id="chart"></div>
</template>
```

chart 2 helper:

```
Template.chart_status.rendered = function() {
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Dropped', 30],
            ['On Course', 120],
            ['DNS', 20],
            ['Finished', 40]
        ],
        colors: {
            'Dropped': '#E60000',
            'On Course': '#00ACED',
            'DNS': '#DBDBDB',
            'Finished': '#00BD07'
        },
        type : 'donut',
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); }
        // onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
        // onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
    },
    donut: {
        title: "Entrant Status",
        label: {
            format: function (value, ratio) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
});
};
```

display code :

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{> chart_cp_overview}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{> chart_status}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

This code above displays only the last chart - chart_status. If I remove any one of the handlebars reference the other chart displays fine, or if I have multiple handlebars to multiple charts whatever was last declared is displayed.

How can I get multiple charts to display within one page? Example is on github at https://github.com/FickleLife/meteor-c3-test

Comment: Now how would you connect this to data from the db? Thats where im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like maybe you are intending the two variable names you have chosen in your template rendered functions, `cpOverview` and `chart`, to bind to the dom elements with those ids.  It won't work that way.

The variable names you have chosen are local to their functions and in any case would not automatically attach to elements with that id even if they were global.  So c3 is binding all these charts to the same  dom element (the docs say the default is `#chart`), and the last one is overriding the prior ones.

You want to bind each chart to its respective element.  You can use `this.firstNode` inside your rendered function (based on the way you have it set up), or use jquery, or `this.find("div#cpOverview")`, and then use the c3 api to bind the chart to it - it looks like `{ bindto: "div#cpOverview" }` may be the one you want.

Comment: And bindto is the answer. Thank you!